# Merge cells sheet loop

Tags: vba, excel

Im currently trying to make an excel sheet to get information from our labs to one file and make a table to fit into the way we need the data to be represented. The problem is that the way out lab reports to us dosent fit the report. I therefor need to merge A1:A2.... Z1:Z2 on close to 50 sheets, so im trying to make a vba to loop that action. Problem is, i cant get the merge to work. 
Im pretty new to VBA. 
My work looks like this now:

```
     Sub WorksheetLoop()
                 Dim WS_Count As Integer
                 Dim I As Integer
    Dim x as integer
    Dim n as integer

                 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

                 For I = 1 To WS_Count
x=0
       For n = 1 to 26


                        Range(Cells(1,x), Cells(1,1+x) Merge x=x+2
Next N                 
Next I
              End Sub
```

Can someone help with the code, it would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work for you. You only really need 2 variables to perform the task, one to loop through the worksheets, and another to loop through your columns on each sheet.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Stops the screen from flickering when the code changes worksheets

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim intColumn As Integer

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 'This tells the code to loop through all of the worksheets in the current workbook without the need to count them
    ws.Activate 'The worksheet needs to be activated for the Range function to run correctly.
    For intColumn = 1 To 26 'For columns A to Z
        ws.Range(Cells(1, intColumn), Cells(2, intColumn)).merge 'Select Row 1 and Row 2 of the column, then merge)
    Next intColumn 'Moves to the next column
Next ws 'Moves to the next worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Always set ScreenUpdating back to True at the end of your code

End Sub
```